# problem in understanding the setRunning (boolean run) method

Tags: java, android, methods

```
  public class GameLoopThread extends Thread 
   {
    static final long FPS = 10;
    private GameView view;
    private boolean running = false;
    public GameLoopThread(GameView view) 
     {
         this.view = view;
     }
   public void setRunning(boolean run) 
   {
         running = run;
   }
   @Override
   public void run() 
   {
         long ticksPS = 1000 / FPS;
         long startTime;
         long sleepTime;
         while (running) 
         {
                Canvas c = null;
                startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                try 
                {
                       c = view.getHolder().lockCanvas();
                       synchronized (view.getHolder()) 
                       {
                              view.onDraw(c);
                       }
                }
                finally 
                {
                       if (c != null) 
                       {
                              view.getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                       }
                }
                sleepTime = ticksPS-(System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime); 
                try 
                {
                       if (sleepTime > 0)
                              sleep(sleepTime);
                       else
                              sleep(10);
                } 
                 catch (Exception e){ 

               }
            }
       }
  }
```

my confusion is that 
  i have initialize-->private boolean running = false;
   after that i assigned-->

```
public void setRunning(boolean run) 
   {
         running = run;
   }
```

so what "running" realy holds, what is the vale of "run"?sombody plz explain setRunning(boolean run) method.

Comment: You're programming threads, and you don't know what a simple setter method like this does? No offense, but you should first start with the basics: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html. Threads are a very complex matter.

Comment: This class is broken anyway since `running` is not declared `volatile` (assuming that `setRunning(...)` will be invoked by another thread).

Comment: running is already declared as false my dear frend..          private boolean running = false;

Answer (score 0):

`run` will hold whatever you pass as the argument to the `setRunning()` method. It will be either `true` or `false`.

From the looks of the code, it appears to control re-drawing the `Canvas`. As long as `running` is `true` (by means of calling `setRunning(true)` on the `Thread`), it will re-draw the `Canvas` every 100 ms (or 10 frames per second).

**EDIT**

You should declare`running` using the `volatile` modifier in order for proper synchronization to occur. If you do not include the modifier, and you call `setRunning()` from another thread, the "expected" result is not guaranteed.

See [here](http://jeremymanson.blogspot.com/2008/11/what-volatile-means-in-java.html).

Comment: what you are trying i understand..but my problem is what will the running variable inside the setRunning method hold.? as running is already initilize to false...

Comment: If it's initialized to ``false`` then it will still and always be ``false`` until you call ``setRunning(true)``.

Comment: Even though running is initialized. It will be changed to whatever run holds.

Comment: so initiation of running to false inn declaration statement "private boolean running = false;"has no effect.....?

Comment: No, this is concurrency. So this can either be true, false or both ;)

Comment: What do you mean by "has no effect"? The effect is that it's initialized to ``false`` and will stay thus until it it's changed. Maybe I'm just having a hard time understanding you question?